# A single word that defines something that is new that was old?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a unique word (any language) that describes the idea of classic, something old that is contemporary, bringing back of a style per se.

Comment: You mean like "revitalized" or "reborn"?

Answer (score 5):

You might consider **retro**, a shortened form of *retrospective*, literally a looking back.  **Retro** describes older ideas, styles, objects, etc. that are considered desirable again.  For example from the *WSJ* blog "Digits", the headline Kodak Goes **Retro** With New Super 8 Camera" over an article that notes

> [Kodak] is using the Consumer Electronics Show to lay out plans for a
>   film camera based on the Super 8 design launched 50 years ago. Kodak
>   stopped producing Super 8 units in 1982, after video cameras savaged
>   the market for home movies made with film.

This film device is half a century old and was superseded by digital technology, but Kodak thinks it could be a popular retro item.

Comment: I was going to suggest *vintage*. But then I read "bringing back.." I guess vintage wouldn't be an appropriate term, would it?

Comment: @BiscuitBoy *Vintage* would be something old of value.  "Classic" captures that.  But I think the vintage item is still seen as of its era, not necessarily trendy.